# wso2is 5.0 oauth2 and active direcoty

Tags: openid, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have a service provider configured for oauth2/openid authentication similar to the one mentioned in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/OpenID+Connect+with+the+WSO2+Identity+Server+and+WSO2+OAuth2+Playground on wso2 is 5.0 and i am having Microsoft Active directory as secondary user store .I am able to login to the application configured with the service provider using AD credentials but the userinfo for AD user name is returned as an empty JSON object. Same time i am able to get the user info details like Email id/firstname,lastname etc for the internal account when logged in .Any suggestion here?

When logged in using AD account User info looks like below

{}

When logged in using internal builtin admin account Userinfo looks like below

{"email":"admin@wso2.com","name":"admin","family_name":"admin","preferred_userna
me":"admin","given_name":"admin"}

Answer (score 0):

You can try the same thing with Identity Server latest release 5.2.0

If the claims are returned for primary user store users and not for secondary user store users, probably it could be a bug. I would recommend you to use the latest product since it has fixes for lot of issues.

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thanks for that Isura, I will try for sure.i had tried with 5.2.0  but was stuck with the issue mentioned here https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4250

Comment: Are you using password grant type? This issue will be fixed soon.

Comment: No isura, I am using CODE as grant type . I tried today and i could see for secondary user store it is returning only subl  {"sub":"tetDomain/skottarathi@carbon.super"}

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the mapped attributes of AD in WSO2 dialect and OIDC dialect?

Ideally, to return the expected claim, the relevant wso2 claim and oidc claim should have same mapped attribute